# Reproduzir próximo vídeo automaticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero fazer uma aplicação local que reproduza os vídeos selecionados pelo usuário através do `checkbox`, e assim que acabar um vídeo, já começa o outro.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Videos</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" id="pacotei" name="Pacote" value="Pacote i">
    <label for="pacotei">CAPSULA</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pacoteii" name="Pacote" value="Pacote ii">
    <label for="pacoteii">CREME</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pacoteiii" name="Pacote" value="Pacote iii">
    <label for="pacoteiii">SACHE</label>
    <br>
    <button onClick="show()"> Mostrar vídeo </button>   

    <div id="videoDiv" style="display: none">

        <video id="video" width="600" height="auto" autoplay loop>
            <source id="source" src="" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(){   
            let pacote = document.querySelector('[name="Pacote"]:checked')
            let source = document.querySelector('#source')

            if(pacote.value === 'Pacote i')
            {
                source.setAttribute('src', './video1.mp4')


            }
            else if(pacote.value === 'Pacote ii') {
                source.setAttribute('src', './video2.mp4')
            }
            else if(pacote.value === 'Pacote iii') {
                source.setAttribute('src', './video3.mp4')
            }

            document.querySelector('#videoDiv').style.display = 'block'
            document.querySelector('#video').load()
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa do evento [`onended`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp) do elemento video para saber quando o video terminou e poder executar o próximo. São necessárias algumas mudanças no seu código, tais como remoção do atributo `loop` da tag video, uso da função `querySelectorAll` em vez de apenas `querySelector` para selecionar as checkbox marcadas (no primeiro pode ser retornado mais de um match, no segundo apenas um match), e mais algumas adaptações para fazer funcionar. Confira no exemplo:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<meta content-type="text/html">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pacotei" name="Pacote" value="Pacote i">
    <label for="pacotei">CAPSULA</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pacoteii" name="Pacote" value="Pacote ii">
    <label for="pacoteii">CREME</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pacoteiii" name="Pacote" value="Pacote iii">
    <label for="pacoteiii">SACHE</label>
    <br>
    <button onClick="show()"> Mostrar vídeo </button>   

    <div id="videoDiv" style="display: none">

        <video id="video" width="600" height="auto" autoplay controls>
            <source id="source" src="" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(){   
            //para selecionar uma ou mais checkboxes, use querySelectAll
            //será retornado um nodelist, similar a um array, com todos
            //os cehckbox que foram selecionados pelo usuario, veja com //console.log(pacotes);
            //pequena mudanca no nome da variavel
            let pacotes = document.querySelectorAll('[name="Pacote"]:checked')
  
            let source = document.querySelector('#source')
     //nesse array vão ser colocados os videos que devem ser tocados
     let videos = [];

     //Nesse trecho você indica quais videos devem ser adicionados ao array
     //Como deve ser adicionado mais de um, você não deveria usar if/else if
            //pacotes[0] é a sua primeira checkbox, pacotes[1] a segunda, pacotes[i] a enesima checkbox
            if(pacotes[0].value === 'Pacote i')
            {
                videos.push('./video1.mp4');

            }
            if(pacotes[1].value === 'Pacote ii') {
                videos.push('./video2.mp4');
            }
            if(pacotes[2].value === 'Pacote iii') {
                videos.push('./video3.mp4');
            }


            document.querySelector('#videoDiv').style.display = 'block'
 
     //agora você precisa carregar o primeiro video (se houver)
     if(videos.length > 0){
                let video_indice = 0;
                let video = document.querySelector('#video');
                //seta o atributo src do video primeiro video video_indice = 0
                source.setAttribute('src', videos[video_indice]);              
         video.load()

                //nesse ponto você deve usar o evento onended no elemento #video
         //que é disparado quando o video termina de rodar
                video.addEventListener('ended', function(){
                    video_indice++;
                    //tocara até o ultimo indice do array videos
                    if(video_indice < videos.length){
                        source.setAttribute('src', videos[video_indice]);              
                 video.load();                        
                    }
                });
            }
            
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Uma melhor abordagem seria inserir os sources dos videos no atributo `value` das checkboxes, evitando ter que indicar posteriormente o que deveria haver no `value` de cada checkbox. Algo assim:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<meta content-type="text/html">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pacotei" name="Pacote" value="./video1.mp4">
    <label for="pacotei">CAPSULA</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pacoteii" name="Pacote" value="./video2.mp4">
    <label for="pacoteii">CREME</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pacoteiii" name="Pacote" value="./video3.mp4">
    <label for="pacoteiii">SACHE</label>
    <br>
    <button onClick="show()"> Mostrar vídeo </button>   

    <div id="videoDiv" style="display: none">

        <video id="video" width="600" height="auto" autoplay controls>
            <source id="source" src="" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(){   
            //para selecionar uma ou mais checkboxes, use querySelectAll
            //será retornado um nodelist, similar a um array, com todos
            //os cehckbox que foram selecionados pelo usuario, veja com //console.log(pacotes);
            //pequena mudanca no nome da variavel
            let pacotes = document.querySelectorAll('[name="Pacote"]:checked')
  
            let source = document.querySelector('#source');


            document.querySelector('#videoDiv').style.display = 'block'
 
     //agora você precisa carregar o primeiro video (se houver) 
            //a partir do nodelist pacotes
     if(pacotes.length > 0){
                let pacote_indice = 0;
                let video = document.querySelector('#video');
                //seta o atributo src do primeiro video 
                //primeiro indice do nodelist, obtido a partir do atributo value
                source.setAttribute('src', pacotes[pacote_indice].value);              
         video.load()

                //nesse ponto você deve usar o evento onended no elemento #video
         //que é disparado quando o video termina de rodar
                video.addEventListener('ended', function(){
                    pacote_indice++;
                    //tocara até o ultimo indice do array pacotes
                    if(pacote_indice < pacotes.length){
                        source.setAttribute('src', pacotes[pacote_indice].value);              
                 video.load();                        
                    }
                });
            }
            
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigão.. muitoo obrigado.. tu e sinistro.. agora vou trabalhar no style da aplicação..vou ate ganhar uma promoção na empresa..  a ideia e apresentar em um tv o trabalho de produção desses itens farmaceuticos..

Comment: Amigao..juven_v consegue me ajuda em uma coisa ?eu consigo colocar um texto para aparecer antes de cada video ?mas esse texto tem que ser relacionado a escolha do video.. exemplo.. se escolher o video de capsula e creme.. antes de cada video preciso colocar um texto com algumas frases dizendo que a pessoa escolheu capsula  e um texto com algumas frases dizendo que escolheu creme.. me ajuda ae.. to enrrolado nao faço ideia de como fazer.. ate vi que o programa cria um nodelist mas nao to sabendo acessar o no do nodelist e passar eventos.